# Writing over a tikz array

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, arrays

i have this array. I need to write over each cell.
For example, i have to write "S" and "E" over the array and not inside.
Can anyone help me?

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex,font=\sffamily,every node/.style={minimum width=1cm,minimum height=1.5em,outer sep=0pt,draw=black,semithick}]
\node []at (0,0) (A) {};
\node [anchor=west] at (A.east) (B) {};
\node [anchor=west,fill=black!20] at (B.east) (C) {S};
\node [anchor=west,fill=black!20] at (C.east) (D) {};
\node [anchor=west] at (D.east) (E) {E};
\node [anchor=west] at (E.east) (F) {};
\node [anchor=west] at (F.east) (G) {};
\draw [->,shorten >=2pt,shorten <=2pt,semithick] (G.south) -- +(0,-1em) -| (A);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: Try with a `label` option: `\node [anchor=west,fill=black!20, label=S] at (B.east) (C) {};`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean something like that?

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex,font=\sffamily,every node/.style={minimum width=1cm,minimum height=1.5em,outer sep=0pt,draw=black,semithick}]
\node []at (0,0) (A) {};
\node [anchor=west] at (A.east) (B) {};
\node [anchor=west,fill=black!20] at (B.east) (C) {S};
\node [anchor=west,fill=black!20] at (C.east) (D) {};
\node [anchor=west] at (D.east) (E) {E};

\node [draw=none,above] at (E.north) {Test};

\node [anchor=west] at (E.east) (F) {};
\node [anchor=west] at (F.east) (G) {};
\draw [->,shorten >=2pt,shorten <=2pt,semithick] (G.south) -- +(0,-1em) -| (A);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes! Thank you! Can you explain me your line `\node [draw=none,above] at (E.north) {Test};` ?

Comment: You already used almost everything that is necessary. I added nothing special, just one line. You want to write above the "E" node, therefore I used the `above` keyword which lets the base coordinate of the "Test" node be its "south" anchor. Therefore it appears above the "E" node's `north` anchor that I defined as absolute base coordinate for the "Test" node with `(E.north)`.